# sed replace command unable to understand at [ ]*

Tags: shell, sed

I am trying to understand one of the bash scrip. There I landed at below sed command, as far as I know, sed replaces first set with 2nd set, but I am confusing at [ ]*, could you please help me what it does.

complete command.

```
sed 's/[ ]*|||[ ] */|||/g'
```

I have executed command by taking a sample file , wherever it see 3 pipes , it is replacing with again ||| pipes.

If that so, I am not able to understand the command, why do we replace same characters

Comment: Looks like it removes space ( trailing and leading before and after of |||

Comment: Yes, it is. But it only replaces single space. If any file have `|||` with more than one space at beginning and end then the above command will only remove single space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part `[ ]*` is a character class (which you can also write as  `*` without the square brackets) and matches optional spaces, in this case to the left and the right of the 3 pipes.

Then replaces it with 3 pipes only without the surrounding spaces.

```
echo "test ||| and ||||| and   | || ||| " | sed 's/[ ]*|||[ ]*/|||/g'
```

Output (tested on macOs 13.1 and Ubuntu GNU sed 4.8)

```
test|||and||||| and   | |||||
```